# Tornado Subprocess confusion

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to build a Tornado web server which takes requests from multiple clients. The request consists of:
a. For a given directory name passed through an URL, zip the files, etc and FTP it out. 
b. Providing a status of sorts if the task is completed.

So, rather than making it a synchronous and linear process, I wanted to break it down into multiple subtasks. The client will submit the URL request and then simply receive a response of sorts 'job submitted'. A bit later, the client can come along asking status on this job. During this time the job obviously has to finish its task.

I am confused between what modules to use - Tornado Subprocess, Popen contructor, Subprocess.Call, etc. I've read Python docs but can't find anything where the task is running longer and Tornado is not supposed to wait for it to finish. So, I need a mechanism to start a job, let it run its course but relinquish the client and then when asked by client provide a status on it.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python programmers widely use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for a set of processes to manage a queue of tasks. [Set up Celery with RabbitMQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html) and write a Celery worker (perhaps with [Celery Canvas](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) that does the work you need: zips a directory, ftps it to somewhere, etc.

The Tornado-Celery integration package provides something that [appears close to what you need to integrate your Tornado application with Celery](http://tornado-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).

This is all a lot of moving parts to install and configure at first, of course, but it will prepare you for a maintainable application architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I haven't written single piece of code on this issue yet. Just having difficulty getting started. Although, I did think this (not the queueing part) was possible simply using Tornado. Have seen some code examples but just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: So, I read about Celery and wanted to try it. Installed using "pip install tornado-celery". Here is the output if I re-install it.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado-celery in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): celery in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado-celery)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado-celery)
Yet, when I do import tcelery, tasks, I get "No module named tasks" error. I am using Python2.7

Comment: Presumably you have the same problem that everyone always has with Python's stupid packaging "system": your default "pip" uses a different python than your default "python". Try "python -m pip install tornado-celery" and see if you get the right pip for your python that way.

Comment: ok, I did that. It helped but didn't see anything glaringly wrong. Now, my simple test script is complaining of ImportError: No module named tasks. My import line says "import tcelery, tasks". I don't have RabbitMQ or Django or anything else installed. 1 step at a time. Just trying to get the basic concept of Tornado & Celery to work. Any thoughts on the error?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Celery user; try asking a new question here for help with Celery, or go to Celery's forum. Apologies.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for pointing me to Celery. Been doing a lot of reading on this. Still haven't been able to get the Tornado celery integration working.